# Check radius around a latitude/longitude

Tags: ios, coordinates, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am making an iOS application for iPhone that will use "Google Maps SDk" to display the user's current location to them using `mapView`.

I am handling the map within my own app, I do not open the phone's installed Google Maps app.

It's a navigation-based app that will alert users when they get to within a certain distance of a predetermined latitude or longitude.

So for instance I have the app running and driving around town (the app simply tracks the user's position on the map - NO turn by turn navigation). In the app I have stored the latitude and longitude of a local shop. Then, when the user comes to within e.g. 500 meters of the shop, a sound will play and the user will see an alert message on the screen.

My question is this: How do I calculate the radius from a given latitude/longitude? The application will have to continuously check to see if it's within a certain radius of any given number of predetermined locations. The application will contain any number of points - not just the one point as in the example.

How do I check whether the user's current latitude or longitude is within a certain radius of the predetermined radius?

Comment: Use CLLocation's distanceFromLocation method to manually check distance or use [Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1) though that's limited to 20 regions at a time.  I am sure there are already several SO answers with examples of both.